# AngularJs views and the DOM (Leaflet and ag-grid)

Tags: angularjs, dom, angular-ui-router

I have an AngualrJS app which is currently single page. It will display either a Leaflet map or two Ag-grid, using `ng-show/hide` on a  boolean value, to show only map or grids at a time.

I was thinking that it would be better to add routing, using ui-router, and have 2 views, one for the Leaflet map & one for the two ag-grid.

I had some problems with the grids, probably because it is necessary to do something like

```
// wait for the document to be loaded, otherwise
// ag-Grid will not find the div in the document.
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    // lookup the container we want the Grid to use
    var eGridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');

    // create the grid passing in the div to use together with the columns & data we want to use
    new agGrid.Grid(eGridDiv, gridOptions);
```

I am *not* asking to solve my coding problem, which I hope to figure out by myself.

Instead, I am asking you to help me understand how AngularJs ui-router views work.

Are they always bound to the DOM, and hidden until the appropriate state is entered, or are they added to/removed from the DOM as the stata changes?

Is there anything else that I need to know, in order to understand how it works under the hood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the requirements correctly, you could first define some conditions and then make the transition to the appropriate view.

In the example code, you can change the `checked` attribute for inputs for changing view displayed.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router'])
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    var helloState = {
      name: 'hello',
      url: '/hello',
      template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
    }

    var aboutState = {
      name: 'about',
      url: '/about',
      template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
    }

    $stateProvider.state(helloState);
    $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
  })
  .directive('selectView', selectView);

let state;
let transitions;

function selectView($state, $transitions) {
  state = $state;
  transitions = $transitions;
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: selectViewLinkFn
  }
}

function selectViewLinkFn($scope, $element) {
  const triggers = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
  transitions.onSuccess({}, () => {
    console.log('onSuccess: ', document.querySelector('h3').innerHTML);
  });
  transitions.onStart({}, () => {
    const findedInView = document.querySelector('h3');
    console.log(`onStart: ${findedInView ? findedInView.innerHTML : 'nothing found'}`);
  });
  setView($scope);

  for (const trigger of triggers) {
    trigger.addEventListener('change', () => setView($scope, true))
  }

  function setView(scope, needDigest) {
    // Check some conditions
    let currentRoute;
    for (const trigger of triggers) {
      if (trigger.checked) {
        currentRoute = trigger.value;
      }
    }
    state.go(currentRoute);
    if (needDigest) {
      scope.$digest();
    }
  }
}


selectView.$inject = ['$state', '$transitions'];
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="helloworld" select-view>
  <label for id="selectHello">Hello</label>
  <input name="selectorForView" type="radio" id="selectHello" value="hello" checked>
  <label for id="selectAbout">About</label>
  <input name="selectorForView" type="radio" id="selectAbout" value="about">

  <h2 ng-bind="selectorForView">
    <h2>
      <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this work for you on localhost? When I "run code snippet" the "About" view is not shown when I select its radio button.

Comment: You need to add event listener. And run `state.go()` inside it. And if you add listener with native javascript, you must execute `$scope.digest()` for apply changes

Comment: I am not sure if you are really answering my question, though. You are calling `document.querySelector()` on a DOM element which is always present, not in a view. I want to understand how & when view elements get added to the DOM

Comment: I think, you could to use transitions hooks to explore this question. I changed the code of the example for a demonstration of available options

Comment: Thank a 1,000,000. This gives me all that I need to implement what I want to.